# Is a "constructive" explosion with reactive armor possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons, armors

I know most reactive armor contains explosives which are designed to take out the shell before it hits the main section of hull. If a shaped charge (or high explosive) detonated within a meter or less of the reactive plate, then would the explosive energy from the projectile combine with the explosive energy of the reactive armor?

Comment: Yes, but the main purpose of reactive armor is to protect against penetrating charges, not explosion shocks.

Comment: So: are two explosions happening in close succession right next to each other stronger than each one by itself?

Comment: Not necessarily. Shock from the explosion of reactive armor would not be nearly strong enough do damage the ordinary armor beneath, but you might (just might) be able to get some cumulative effect from both shocks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this does not seem to be a question relating to Worldbuilding in any way, shape, or form. Voting to close. This is something you could ask in the Sandbox, or in chat, and people will be happy to help you with.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there would be additive effects, but they would not be significant in any way.

The purpose of [reactive armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_armour) is to disrupt penetrating attacks, not shocks.  The idea is that the armor of a tank is much too thick and strong to be defeated with a plain old high explosive.  Instead, we attack with things like [shaped charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaped_charge) which are designed to focus their power on a very small area.  These weapons are very precise in their design, and depend upon this precision to operate.  Reactive armor creates a region that these shaped charges must penetrate which is not conducive to such precision operations.  It disrupts the jets (or breaks apart the kinetic penetrator rod) by creating an environment where it is difficult to maintain structural integrity.

The reactive armor does not need a lot of explosive material to do this, and it is thinly distributed across the tank.  Even if a HE explosion were to activate all of the reactive armor, the effect would be minor.

Comment: Not only that, but -- naturally -- the shock wave takes the path of least resistance, and that path is the air away from the tank.

Comment: Couldn't triggering several adjacent reactive components in a well timed pattern make constructive shockwaves? Is it just too little HE over too much space, or the shape of the components or armor makes that not reasonable?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt It would be a mighty challenge.  Besides the issue RonJohn mentioned (where most of the energy goes into the air, not the tank), making constructive shockwaves and *doing* something with them are very different beasts.  If you look at what we do for nuclear weapons, you can see the extraordinary design parameters needed to initiate fission with constructive shockwaves.  Doing so in a less controlled environment would be incredibly difficult.

Answer (score 3):

[Explosive Reactive Armour](https://below-the-turret-ring.blogspot.ca/2016/04/explosive-reactive-armor-some-history.html) ([ERA](https://infogalactic.com/info/Reactive_armour)) works on the principle of disrupting incoming penetrators, particularly high velocity streams of liquid metals from a HEAT shell. The explosion of a [HEAT](https://infogalactic.com/info/High-explosive_anti-tank_warhead) shell is focused to exploit the "[Munroe effect](https://infogalactic.com/info/Shaped_charge#Munroe_effect)" and focus the energy into a highly accelerated jet of liquid metal. Detonating the shell at the wrong point means the jet will not form properly before it strikes the armour, and the ERA plate being driven into the exploding jet will both change the distance the jet has to travel, and even change the direction of the jet, if the plate is moving at an angle relative to the jet.

[image]

*ERA in action*

In the ever evolving dance between offence and defence, compound warheads were developed to detonate the ERA brick, then fire a second charge through the opening created by the exploded brick. The former Soviet Union had countered by stacking layers of ERA bricks on top of each other, demonstrating that they were not worried about any additive effects of multiple detonations near the surface of the tank.

[image]

*Soviet era tank with single layer ERA. While I can't find a picture right now, there were efforts to stack layers of ERA bricks to protect against tandem warheads*